# подскажите как в bootsrap 3 выровнить колонки по центру?

Tags: bootstrap

Всем привет подскажите как в boostrap 3 выровнить эти блоки по центру?

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-3">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img src="#" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center"><b>text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-lg text-uppercase u-btn-green cs-font-weight-700 cs-font-size-11 cs-color-white cs-color-white--hover cs-bg-primary--hover cs-brd-none rounded-0 cs-px-20 speaker_button_container" href="#" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-3">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img src="#" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center"><b>text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-lg text-uppercase u-btn-green cs-font-weight-700 cs-font-size-11 cs-color-white cs-color-white--hover cs-bg-primary--hover cs-brd-none rounded-0 cs-px-20 speaker_button_container" href="#" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-3">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img src="#" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-center"><b>text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-lg text-uppercase u-btn-green cs-font-weight-700 cs-font-size-11 cs-color-white cs-color-white--hover cs-bg-primary--hover cs-brd-none rounded-0 cs-px-20 speaker_button_container" href="#" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Если у меня 4 блока, то все классно они выравниваются по центру, а если 3 блока то нет, как сделать стандартными средствами boostrap что бы они выравнивались всегда по центру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот готовое решение: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLJVRm

```
.container>.row>some cols
```

Смысл в том что сетка бутстрапа должна состоять из 12колонок (4 * 3 = 12)
И быть обрамленной в контейнер или безразмерный контейнер (.container-fluid) в котором лежит .row
Если важно сохранить фиксированную ширину колонки, то меняем ширину контейнера

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем то, дело в том что у меня по горизонтали может быть от 1 колонки до 4, и мне надо сделать так что бы если 1 колонка или 2 или 3 то они выравнивались по центру row

Comment: если колонки три то ставьте col-**-4
если колонки четыре то ставьте col-**-3